# How to pass user credentials as JSON

Tags: rest, post

I want to post user credentials as JSON data after calling a URL. How to achieve it.

```java
var url:java.net.URL = new java.net.URL("https://www.client.com/login/session"); 
var conn:javax.net.ssl.HttpURLConnection = url.openConnection();
```

After openConnection I have to pass user credentials as JSON data. Please advise

Comment: What does the specification of the API you are calling look like for authentication?

Comment: I presume that’s some 3rd party, not a Domino XPages server you want to access. Don’t use a HttpURLConnection. It’s too much work. Use the Apache http client. Works like a charm

Comment: api needs user id and password in json body

Comment: Can you please share Apache http Client code pls.

Comment: @SvenHasselbach; Yes its for authentication to get a token

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: This has nothing to do with XPages, so please remove that tag. Also you can find about 2.500 other questions here that describe how to do a HTTP POST in Java and send JSON: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java+http+post+json